# Нужна библиотека для работы с RDP на уровне TCP

Tags: c#, rdp

Ищу библиотеку, которая позволила бы общаться с удаленным компьютером по протоколу RDP, но без окон. Мне не нужно управление. По сути мне надо лишь проверять доступность множества серверов по RDP.

Пока видел: 1. ActiveX компонент с wrapper'ом. Но он требует окно, что логично. Но мне не подходит. 2. Смотрел спецификацию протокола. Там все не просто. Много структур. Для всего, вроде есть описание и возможно придется обходиться этим.

может есть чтото новое и по проще?

Comment: Если "мне только проверить" - второй вариант хорош, вам не нужно весь протокол разбирать, только инициализацию соединения по сути провести

Comment: Самый простой вариант - просто пытаться через сокеты подключиться на порт RDP. Успешное подключение не гарантирует, что RDP реально доступно, но если подключиться так не получилось - значит подключение точно не доступно.